# ExtJS 4 Using memory / paging memory proxy with remote data source

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In my application I want to load a set of data from a remote source (in JSON format) to continue working with it completely locally (filtering, sorting, paging). `store.load()` operation have to get data from a remote source as well.

As I understand most suited store proxy type is [`Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy), but its sub class of [`Ext.data.proxy.Client`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Client), thus it can't work with remote data source (which I can set with `url` property for `Ext.data.proxy.Server`-based proxies).

If I add `data` directly to the store config all works as expected.

What proxy type is best suited for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

I had a  similar problem but not with a local file but gettin json from a server, I used a buffered store to do that:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.BufferedStore
(same on extjs 4)

Personally i use memory proxy to save datas only during execution. reloading or closing the page datas Always are deleted (sort of browser ram).

if equipment/get_all_devices is a JSON try to use a bufferedstore with json reader. if you use buffered store Ajax request use limit with your page size (pageSize: 25)

useful with big amount of datas

Comment: I dont use local file, I get data from remote server in JSON format.
Also buffered store is opposite for my needs, as I have relatively small data set that I could load entirely while buffered store load data set by pages and save already loaded pages in the memory.

Comment: how about change proxy after store.load()?

Comment: But what if I want to reload data from remote source later? Change proxy again on the fly, load data, chagne back to `pagingmemory`? Probably it could work, but seems like 'dirty' solution. I think about making of custom proxy combining ajax and paging memory functional.

Comment: yes dirty solution, maybe make a custom proxy work, but I can't help on this